# querySelector throws error now data format has changed

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a query selector to read an input when a user chooses various buttons, before the buttons had these options and it worked fine:

8x10 inch

12x16 inch

20x24 inch

Then I updated the options to this format:

8" x 10"

12" x 10"

20" x 24"

Now I get this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'button[data-value="12" x 16""]' is not a valid selector.
```

Here is my querySelector Script:

```
    <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var rad = document.querySelectorAll('.swatch input[type="radio"]');
    var prev = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
        rad[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
            (prev) ? console.log(prev.value): null;
            if (this !== prev) {
                prev = this;
            }
            console.log(this.value)
            document.querySelector('button[data-value="'+this.value+'"]').click()
        });
    }
    
//     (function() {
//       jQuery('.swatch :radio').change(function() {
//         var optionIndex = jQuery(this).closest('.swatch').attr('data-index');
//         var optionValue = jQuery(this).val();
//       });
//     });

  })

</script>
```

I'm trying to get the script to read the new format which includes the quotation marks.

I hope this makes sense. Thank you if you can help.

Dale.

Comment: You have to escape the `"` in the string. Now you are immediately ending the string

Comment: I see that the " from the size option may end the string, how do I 'escape' it?

Comment: `document.querySelector('button[data-value="\'+this.value+\'"]').click()`. This is how it is done with the help of `\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the string by preceding every `'` or `"` by a backslash.

So you can do `document.querySelector('button[data-value="'+this.value.replace(/"/, '\\"')`+'"]').click()` to make sure every double quote is preceded by a backslash. However, you might still have problems if you have single quotes or other disallowed characters.

Another option is to abuse `JSON.stringify()`:

```
document.querySelector('button[data-value='+JSON.stringify(this.value)+']').click()
```

Note you don't need the add quotes to the side of the string anymore since they are provided by `JSON.strinfigy()`.

Comment: Thanks mousetail, I remember doing all this with the stringifys and console logging endlessly when I tried to build an app in node 18 months ago, safe to say it didn't stay with me, nor did the patience to figure it out, very kind of you to help.